# Stack css sticky elements within one scrollable

Tags: css, sticky

I'm using css position:sticky and I have Header sticky element in the root and a sticky *dt* element for each section inside *dl* element.

But currently *dt* element overflow header element when stuck. 
Is there a pure css way to make *dt* elements stuck below header **if we don't know header height**? Header content is dynamic, it might wrap on window width change.

```css
.header {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #6783fc;
  background-color: #3c5fe8;
}

dl > div {
  padding: 24px 0 0 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

dt {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background: #B8C1C8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989EA4;
  border-top: 1px solid #717D85;
  color: #FFF;
  font: bold 18px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0 12px;
}

dd {
  font: bold 20px/45px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

dd + dd {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Andrew W.K.</dd>
    <dd>Apparat</dd>
    <dd>Arcade Fire</dd>
    <dd>At The Drive-In</dd>
    <dd>Aziz Ansari</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: There is no **pure css** way to make dt elements stuck below header if we **don't know header height**. you need to use JS to get the header height first and then set it to top of dt.